# need help writing a sql query with multiple join conditions

Tags: sql, postgresql

i have a sql query currently with a multiple inner join

```
select game_id, start_time_utc, t.name from games g
inner join teams t
on g.home_team_id = t.team_id 
or g.away_team_id = t.team_id
```

the problem is i want `t.name` for both the `home_team_id` and the `away_team_id` however it is just giving the first instance with his `home_team_id`
how do i modify the sql query so i get back both the `home team name` and the `away team name`

Comment: It would be helpful if you'd provide the schema for your `teams` and `games tables

Comment: I guess you want to join `teams` twice once for the home and once for the away team. But to a certain answer you should [edit] the question and provide a [example], i.e. the `CREATE` statements of the tables or other objects involved (paste the **text**, don't use images, don't link to external sites), `INSERT` statements for sample data (dito) and the desired result with that sample data in tabular text format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join the table twice.

```
select game_id, start_time_utc, t.name as home_team_name, t2.name as away_team_name 
from games g
inner join teams t on g.home_team_id = t.team_id 
inner join teams t2 on g.away_team_id = t2.team_id
```

Answer (score 1):

You could select each team name using a correlated subquery:

```
select g.game_id, g.start_time_utc, 
    (select name from teams t where t.team_id=g.home_team_id) HomeTeam,
    (select name from teams t where t.team_id=g.away_team_id) AwayTeam
from games g;
```